# Mongoose query returns empty array

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I'm using Express to do a find operation in a Mongo collection and return the result. I know that there is data in the collection, but the result array comes back empty. I suspect that it's an issue with the schema, but can't figure out what. Thoughts?

Route:

const PlotStatus = require('../models/plotStatus');

```
exports.plotStatuses = async (req, res) => {
    const plotStatus = await PlotStatus.find({
        company: req.user.companyCode
    }).lean();
    if (!plotStatus) {
        throw new Error('Plot Statuses not found');
    } else {
        res.send(plotStatus);
    }
};
```

Model:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const plotStatusSchema = new Schema(
    {
        recordDate: Date,
        blockName: String,
        growerName: String,
        company: String,
        variety: String,
        planted: Number,
        region: String,
        yieldInKG: Number,
        currentRipeness: String,
        nextStage: String,
        timeToNextInDays: Number,
        status: Number
    },
    { bufferCommands: false },
    { collection: 'plotStatuses' }
);

const ModelClass = mongoose.model('plotStatus', plotStatusSchema);

module.exports = ModelClass;
```

Sample plotStatus:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("stringhere"),
    "recordDate" : ISODate("2018-01-02T12:50:51.236Z"),
    "blockName" : "name",
    "growerName" : "grower's name",
    "company" : "mycompany",
    "variety" : "myvariety",
    "planted" : 2010,
    "region" : "myregion",
    "yieldInKG" : 960,
    "changeInPcnt" : -1.6,
    "currentRipeness" : "ripeness",
    "nextStage" : "nextstage",
    "timeToNextInDays" : 42,
    "status" : 0
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, got it.

Typically, Mongoose infers the collection name from the model name, but you can pass it explicitly. Apparently, plotStatus => plotStatuses was a bridge too far. This fixed it:

```
const ModelClass = mongoose.model(
    'plotStatus',
    plotStatusSchema,
    'plotStatuses'
);
```